# fastreport doesn't show Arabic number at the beginning

Tags: fastreport

I don't know how to explain it .. but my data is in Arabic lang.
and fastreport is fine showing the data, but when the data starts with a number in the report it goes at the end of the line. like when i add number at the beginning of a line it jumped at the end of it 
any help?

Answer (score 0):

set the "RigthToLeft" property of Text to "True"